# storage values from label entry

Tags: python, numpy, storage

I am working on appJar in order to show my answers. I am using getLabel to get my entry values, but then I want to operate with those (np). So, how can I operate with the entry values?

```
import numpy as np
from appJar import gui 

def launch(win):
    app.showSubWindow(win)

app=gui("JM-UofA2018","600x100")

#Title
app.addLabel("title", "Welcome to Open Pit Design-Angles Tool")
app.setLabelBg("title", "red")
app.setLabelFg("title", "blue")
#Label Instructions
app.addLabel("Select one Button:")
# these go in the main window
app.addButtons(["Catch Bench (CB)","Horizontal Distance (HD)","Bench Face Angle (BFA)"], launch)


def press(button):
    if button == "Cancel":
        app.stop() 
    else:
        app.getLabel("Height")
        app.getLabel("IRA")
        app.getLabel("BFA")

        CB = (Height*((1/(np.tan(IRA*np.pi/180))-(1/(np.tan(BFA*np.pi/180))))))
        print(CB)

app.startSubWindow("Catch Bench (CB)", modal=True)
app.addLabel("l1", "Input: Height,IRA and BFA")
app.addLabel("Height")
app.addNumericEntry("Height")
app.addLabel("IRA")
app.addNumericEntry("IRA")

app.addLabel("BFA")
app.addNumericEntry("BFA")

app.addButtons(["Accept", "Cancel"], press)
app.stopSubWindow()

app.go()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please add `python` and `numpy` tags to your post, so you draw the attention of the right people.  Remove `storage` which doesn't really apply here.  Also, I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but perhaps it's because I don't know appjar.  However, I suspect you need to use `getEntry`, and you need to assign the returned values variables and pass the variables to numpy.

Comment: Be sure to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You're close!

Answer (score 0):

`getLabel()` returns the string contents of the label, but you need the contents of the numeric entries, where the user inputs data, so use `getNumericEntry()` instead.

You also need to assign these returned, user-entered values to the corresponding variables (which you are currently trying to use without having defined). For example:

```
IRA = app.getNumericEntry("IRA")
```